# CloudIdentity on openstacksdknet (Could not find user)

Tags: c#, .net, cloud, openstack

I am working on a Cloud Backup client by using [OpenStack SDK .NET](http://www.openstacknetsdk.org/) and I'm trying to identify with user credentials, sent to me from the server administrator. For the test everything seems to work perfect on the python openstack client. I use Advanced Rest Client Chrome Extension to get the token:

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xx:5000/v3/auth/tokens
POST METHOD

Header:
Content-Type: application/json

Body:

{
    "auth": {
        "identity": {
            "methods": [
                "password"
            ],
            "password": {
                "user": {
                    "id": "e5f4ec652c5e4d97b8fe6266113ac9f3",
                    "password": "PasswordFromAdministrator"
                }
            }
        },
        "scope": {
            "project": {
                "id": "9b594b7c51484702b6b4d1a91c6aa2ed"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The response is with status Created (201):

```
Date: Tue, 20 Oct 2015 10:28:26 GMT 
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) 
X-Subject-Token: d3b8133fea7846abbe2f023f410e3294
Vary: X-Auth-Token 
x-openstack-request-id: req-a517ee76-9353-4c7c-b646-47f566c84838
Content-Length: 1756 
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
```

With the X-Subject-Token I log into a openstack server with python client with the command:

```
openstack --os-url http://xx.xx.xx.xx:5000/v3 --os-identity-api-version 3 --os-token=d3b8133fea7846abbe2f023f410e3294
```

And the authorization is OK. Projects, Users, Containers, everything is listed perfect.
The problem comes, when I try to use OpenStack APIs for .NET. I use OpenStack SDK .NET and CloudIdentity Class in all forms (CloudIdentity, CloudIdentityWithProject) and the response allays is "Could not find user XXXX  (Disable debug mode to suppress these details.)":

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var username = "myuser";
        var password = "PasswordFromAdministrator";
        var project_name = "backup";
        var project_id = "9b594b7c51484702b6b4d1a91c6aa2ed";
        var auth_url = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:5000/v3";
        var region = "RegionOne";

        var identity = new CloudIdentityWithProject()
        {
            Username = username,
            Password = password,
            ProjectId = new ProjectId(project_id),
            ProjectName = project_name
        };

        //var identity = new CloudIdentity()
        //{
            //Username = username,
            //Password = password,
        //};

        var identityProvider = new OpenStackIdentityProvider(new Uri(auth_url));

        var conn = new CloudFilesProvider(identity, identityProvider);

        // step-2
        var containers = conn.ListContainers();
        foreach (var container in containers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Container Name: {1}", container.Name));
        }
    }
```

[image: Exeption]

The user exists in the server and have administrative role for the project. 
So the questions are:
1. Is this the right way to identity in openstack server?
2. If not, is there better API for backup files in openstack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, at this time, OpenStack.NET only supports OpenStack Identity v2.0, not v3. Perhaps you can ask your administrator if there is a v2 identity endpoint available for you to use?

The [roadmap](https://github.com/openstacknetsdk/openstack.net/milestones) has scheduled support for identity v3 in OpenStack.NET v1.5.2 (we are currently on v1.5.0.1). But that won't happen for a few months.