# Openstackdotnet SDK Object Storage Object Versioning

Tags: c#, .net, cloud, storage, openstack

I am working on a Cloud Backup client by using [OpenStack SDK .NET](http://www.openstacknetsdk.org/). In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33235106/cloudidentity-on-openstacksdknet-could-not-find-user) I had problem with identification, and it was solved perfect. Now I tested almost every functionality that I need, but one thing seems not working right.
I need to create functionality for object versioning in object storage swift. I read in official Openstack documentation that I need to add a header to the Rest:

```
X-Versions-Location: myversionlocation
```

In my library I modified my method for creating of containers from:

```
public void CreateContainer(string _containerName)
{
    filesProvider.CreateContainer(_containerName, null, null, false, null);
}
```

to:

```
public void CreateContainer(string _containerName)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> versioningHeader = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    versioningHeader.Add("X-Versions-Location", "versions");
    filesProvider.CreateContainer(_containerName, versioningHeader, null, false, null);
}
```

There is no problem when I upload a file in container, but when I upload it for second time my applicaion throws an ResponseException: {"Unexpected HTTP error: PreconditionFailed"} in this line:

```
public void UploadFile(string _containerName, string _fileName, ThrottledStream _stream)
{
    filesProvider.CreateObject(_containerName, _stream, _fileName, null, 4096, null, "RegionOne");
}
```

Is this the right way to create container with enabled versioning?

Answer (score 0):

Based on that error, are you perhaps sending the "if-none-match" header when creating the object? When that header is set, and you attempt to upload a file which already exists in the container, that error is thrown. I don't believe you can use that header with versioning, as the check is based on the name, not the file hash of what is being uploaded. Just a guess. :-)

Below is a console application which uploads a file twice, before uploading a new version, to demonstrate that this should work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using net.openstack.Core.Domain;
using net.openstack.Core.Providers;
using net.openstack.Providers.Rackspace;

namespace CloudFilesVersioning
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var identityUrl = new Uri("{identity-url}");
            var identity = new CloudIdentityWithProject
            {
                Username = "{user}",
                ProjectName = "{project-name}",
                Password = "{password}"
            };
            const string region = "RegionOne";

            var identityProvider = new OpenStackIdentityProvider(identityUrl, identity);
            var filesProvider = new CloudFilesProvider(null, identityProvider);

            // Create versions container
            const string versionContainerName = "mycontainer-versions";
            filesProvider.CreateContainer(versionContainerName, region: region);

            // Create main container
            const string containerName = "mycontainer";
            var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"X-Versions-Location", versionContainerName}
            };
            filesProvider.CreateContainer(containerName, headers, region);

            // Upload the initial file
            filesProvider.CreateObjectFromFile(containerName, @"C:\thing-v1.txt", "thing.txt", region: region);

            // Upload the same file again, this should not create a new version
            filesProvider.CreateObjectFromFile(containerName, @"C:\thing-v1.txt", "thing.txt", region: region);

            // Upload a new version of the file
            filesProvider.CreateObjectFromFile(containerName, @"C:\thing-v2.txt", "thing.txt", region: region);
        }
    }
}
```